# Why was my question closed? I would like to re-open it

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016067/how-do-you-redirect-other-apps-to-your-own-app-on-android

That is my question. I do not know why it was closed, as my question does not meet what it was closed for. I would like it re-opened. The question is actually a very good question, although the answer might not be known quickly. Is it simply the fact that I asked for some code because I am new at this? My question is possible, and I feel it is quite understandable. If it isn't, could someone suggest what I need too change. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the close note:

> This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, **overly broad**, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

*How to ...* questions normally get closed because they are "*Give me the code*" questions and are not welcome here. If you get stuck on a **specific** task on your way, you can ask about it but not just ask how to do it all for you.

Also a Q&A site is supposed for questions that are specifically answerable. So please do not as for *hints* either.

**Generally you can ask a question on Stack Overflow if you have done your research, not before.**

Comment: Exactly, came here to post this very answer. This is an appropriate question: `How do I force the Java interpreter to convert this type into that type? { code blah blah code }` and this is not: `How do I do type conversion in Java? Thanks for the help, you guys are wonderful, kiss hug kiss hug`

Comment: Alright, I changed my question, is it better now? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016067/how-do-you-redirect-other-apps-to-your-own-app-on-android

Comment: @juergen d, But since I really don't know what code to use, I did not add any. However, I think my question is not better asked, and does show that I did research, I believe I am even on the right track, I just don't know how to use it.

Comment: @AceLegend: Your question got reopened now.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Although, I don't know how a question on Meta could get marked down, that seems odd?

Comment: @AceLegend: [Voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: @juergend, Weird. Well, okay. Anyway, thanks for your help, looks like I'm back in business thanks to you.

Answer (score 2):

Here on StackOverflow do not like the "Code this for me" questions. We can understand that someone is new at this. This is why we will gladly help if you provide tries that failed, question you have while you progress in your code or any specific questions about a problem you encountered.

I recommend you read online about what the first step towards your goal might be. Then if you get stuck on something and can't find the answer online or don't understand the answers you found, come back here ask a specific question with you current progress and you will have all the help you want.

Answer (score 2):

You never showed what you tried.

So in the end it is not a useful question to the community.

If you have a question that you need help with, you first need to show [what you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).